# What is the maximum SQlite database usage 1 app on an Android device can use?

Tags: android

1. What is the maximum SQlite database usage 1 app on an Android device can use?
2. What is a typical size of an on device SQlite database on an Android device?

Is there a limit on the on device database usage per app? Or is it free for all across all your apps?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: What do you mean with usage? Three queries a day? Or what?